# How to use DataReader to read from a read only characteristic using C++/WinRT

Tags: windows, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, c++-winrt

Using C++/WinRT, VS2017, Win10

My Bluetooth LE device has a main Service that contains a characteristic to write commands and a characteristic to read replies from the device.

The characteristic to write commands (txService below) is both readable and writable but if you read it you will only see the command that you previously wrote.  The characteristic to read replies from the device (rxService below) is only readable.

The BTLE device takes commands as strings such as in "AT+CMODE=5\n" to set a value via txService and "AT+CMODE?\n" to query the current value from the rxService. Even for commands that set a value, however, the device will reply to the rxService with a rely such as "+CMODE:OK\n" if the command was written.

My txService (transmit) and rxService (retrieve) variables have already been initiated at this point and I instantiate the DataWriter with

```
auto writer = Windows::Storage::Streams::DataWriter();
```

and set the string that will be the command, in this case a query, with

```
writer.WriteString(L"AT+CMODE?\\n"); // backslash has been escaped.
```

I then transmit the command to the device with

```
auto status = co_await txService.WriteValueWithResultAsync(writer.DetachBuffer(),   winrt::Windows::Devices::Bluetooth::GenericAttributeProfile::GattWriteOption::WriteWithoutResponse);
```

The write can be verified with

```
if (status.Status() == GattCommunicationStatus::Success){}
```

This brings me to my problem.  I have been unable to format a DataReader to read from the rxService (characteristic). How would I go about doing that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Ed

Answer (score 0):

The [DataReader Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams.datareader?view=winrt-22621) has a method called `FromBuffer(IBuffer)`. You could use it to read the Buffer that added to the characteristic.

For more information, please check: [GATT Service-Respond to Read and Write requests](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-server#respond-to-read-and-write-requests) and [GATT Client - Perform Read/Write operations on a characteristic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/gatt-client#perform-readwrite-operations-on-a-characteristic)

Answer (score 0):

My solution, with help from several sources, was to attach a callback for when the value of the Rx (receive) characteristic changes before doing any writes like this

```
rxCharacteristic.ValueChanged([&](GenericAttributeProfile::GattCharacteristic characteristic,
    GenericAttributeProfile::GattValueChangedEventArgs eventArgs) {
    DataReader reader = DataReader::FromBuffer(eventArgs.CharacteristicValue());
    // Note this assumes value is string the characteristic type must be determined before reading
    // This can display junk or maybe blowup
    std::wcout << "rxCharacteristic New Value - " << reader.ReadString(eventArgs.CharacteristicValue().Length()).c_str() << std::endl;
});
```

Now, every time the value of the Rx changes (with each write), this callback will fire and the DataReader will run and the wcout will write the new value.

I'm new to WinRt, I'm new to Bluetooth LE, and I'm new to this type of Lambda expression.  But I'm getting there ;-)